# Bioplastics from eggshells

Tags: organic-chemistry, home-experiment

There are many resources online which talk about projects making bioplastic from egg shells. However none of these actually show or describe the procedure needed to make it. Does anyone know a site/paper which one could use to figure out how to do this for a science fair project?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of this site. For any questions about how it works, consult the [help].

Comment: What kinds of bioplastic? Bones are made of calcium phosphate, so egg shells won't do.

Answer (score 2):

Eggshell is 95% calcium carbonate. It seems more likely to be used as an additive in a composite plastic.  Testing composite plastics produced from adding ground eggshell to common plastics may make for an interesting science project.

References:

[Dissertation on meat and bone meal derived plastics](http://tigerprints.clemson.edu/all_dissertations/1337/)

Patricio Toroa et. al. Eggshell, a new bio-filler for polypropylene composites

Comment: And I don't relay see the benefit of the calcium carbonate coming from eggshells other than to advertise with "bio" buzzwords..

Comment: Eggshell is a waste product poultry producers have to pay to landfill.  The goal in using egg shell in plastics is to avoid paying money to send egg shells to the landfill and instead use the shells to save money on plastic packaging for eggs.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggshell_and_protein_membrane_separation -

Comment: @_Agriculturist I can't completely follow your argument about using egg shells in plastic surgery (in small quantum) to avoid having to pay for depositing them, as there are many clay soils that would profit form egg shells.

Comment: @Gyro  You seem confused about the term "bioplastics".  This article should help..   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioplastic     ---

Comment: Yes, I read bioplastics as some kind of bone-replacement, or something like that, within our bodies.

Comment: Gyro - You have a good point, IUPAC discourages the use of the term bioplastic.

Comment: Btw, where do the hens get all that calcium carbonate they need for laying eggs? Wouldn't egg shells be a perfect recycling food supplement?

Comment: Please post this as a separate question.

Comment: I don't think this appropriate to *chemistry*.stackexchange. And I would say, YES it is, but I can't cite resources.